# How to use CSS graph in java

Tags: java, graph, frontend

Is there a way to implement good design graphs in java?

I come from web front end, and I'd like to create graphs with amazing style effect in java - Just like how I would do in javascript and CSS?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to those libs:

- [JfreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)
- [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm)

I can miss some others.

I built a month ago an J2EE app (with servlet and JSP page) and I had to deal with charts and honestly I dropped the idea of doing it in Java. The reason? The difficulty of finding a good API/lib and the poor documentation of these.

I personally chose to use AngularJS and my data are produced with a Java program (NOT telling you that's the best method).

My charts are made with Zingchart. I found it very powerful due to the fact that the charts can be made from JSON (easy to make in Java).

Hope I helped you.